# Tricky remove, replace and transform transformation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to remove the first row, and then push the value in the second row as a column header, replacing the original value.

**Data**

```
    Unnamed: 0_Date val1    val2
0           
1   state       
2   AA1             63  65
3   AA2             0   0
```

**Desired**

```
    state   val1  val2
2   AA1     63    65
3   AA2     0     0
```

**Doing**

```
df.columns = (df.columns + '_' + df.iloc[0])
df.iloc[0] = ''
df = out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Trying the script above however this is not removing the specified row, nor is it replacing the original column value. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you get this DataFrame from a csv file or something?

Comment: I can't guess what you are doing with your columns command.  You need `df.rename( {'unnamed': df.iloc[1]['unnamed']} )`, then you need to drop the first two rows.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I create it from a  previous command

Comment: Hi @Lynn. How did you read your data file?

Comment: @Corralien out = pd.read_csv("df.csv")

Comment: Can you create a dataframe constructor code for your input dataframe?

Comment: @Lynn, you could set column names explicitly `[state val1 val2]` if you know the dataset purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df = df.drop(0)
df.rename({'unnamed': df.iloc[0,0]}, axis=1).drop(1)
```

Output:

```
  state val1 val2
2   AA1   63   65
3   AA2    0    0
4   BB2    0    5
```

Used data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'unnamed': ['', 'state', 'AA1', 'AA2', 'BB2'],
    'val1': ['', '', 63, 0, 0],
    'val2': ['', '', 65, 0, 5],
})
```